# Get json string in C#

Tags: c#, json

I have created a post method for sending json like below.,

**daywiseInventory Page C# -**

```
public string daywiseInventory(string JsonQuery)
{
    try
    {
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("www.example.com/booking.aspx");
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string json = JsonQuery;

            streamWriter.Write(json);
        }
        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            return responseText;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.Message;
    }
}
```

And I want to get the posting json in Booking Page_Load. How can i code for this?

when i trying the below code in page_load was not helping. it through Invalid URI: The URI is empty Error.

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create ("") as HttpWebRequest;
HttpWebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse () as HttpWebResponse;

// Read the response
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (response.GetResponseStream ());
var responseText = reader.ReadToEnd ();
```

I am new to this json. So kindly explain how to get the json string that i have post?

Comment: Correct content type for json is `application/json`

Comment: thanks uriil i will change..

Comment: Are you saying that you want the value of `JsonQuery` in the `Page_Load` method?

Comment: s sir. i want the JsonQuery value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code:

```cs
HttpWebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create ("") as HttpWebRequest;
```

You haven't specified the Uri in the `WebRequest.Create("")`, so to correct it, add a URI to connect to.

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create ("http://my.website.to/connect.to.aspx") as HttpWebRequest;
```

Comment: I have specify the www.example.com/booking.aspx url in post method. I have return the response too. Is possible to get the json response without specifying the url?

Comment: @Sagotharan it's really unclear what you need. Get JSON responce, without sending request?

Comment: I am new this sir, so only it get confusing. see my project sir.. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2w9Ww9b3kRvRm15M0VrYVhiRFU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: i have post a json to www.mcubicsoftware.com/booking.aspx/HttpGet url, and i want get the same json in httpget function sir. It just sending and receiving json string program sir. I have done post method. but i don;t know the get method. is this explanation help understand me sir?